# Proper way to set up this XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

UPDATED DUE TO ERROR IN CODE AND DESCRIPTION

I am pretty new to XML but am holding my own when creating an XML file using the built in functions.

I can create the file like so...

```
$xml['doc'] =       new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

and so forth and it outputs like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adf>
elements...
</adf>
```

what I need is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?adf version="1.0"?>
<adf>
elements...
</adf>
```

Looking for the correct way to add <adf version="1.0"?>? It does not need a closing tag.I am following a specific format required. Specifically ADF 1.0 as documented here....
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-lead_Data_Format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<?target content?>` construct is called an [XML processing instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction).

`<?xml ?>` is a special case: it must be the very first thing in the document. Your `<?adf version="1.0" ?><?xml version="1.0"?>` example is not well-formed XML.  However `<?xml version="1.0"?><?adf version="1.0" ?>` is fine.

You can create a processing instruction easily with [`createProcessingInstruction`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createprocessinginstruction.php)

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$pi = $doc->createProcessingInstruction('adf', 'version="1.0"');
$doc->appendChild($pi);
// you still need a root element to be well-formed
$doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('adf'));
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This code will print the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?adf version="1.0"?>
<adf/>
```

Note that the content of processing instructions *is not parsed* by an xml processor--it is just text, like comments. If you use an xml-like attribute syntax inside them, you will have to parse it yourself.

In the vast majority of situations, using real elements and attributes is a better choice than using a custom processing instruction. (ADF requires a processing instruction, so of course you should use one in this case.)

Comment: This answered it, thanks. What i needed was the processing instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Your desired output would not be valid XML, as nothing is permitted before the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration. Your custom content will need to be part of the normal XML flow.